# AngularJS receiving checkbox value = false in a controller when checked(selected) from UI

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am new to AngularJS.
I have a code like below,

On selection of a record by clicking on checkbox I receive "existingEntitlement.Selected" in the function addRemoveSelectedRecord() as false. I expect it as true.

```
 <tr dir-paginate="existingEntitlement in allEntitlements>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="existingEntitlement.Selected" ng-change="addRemoveSelectedRecord({{existingEntitlement.entitlementId}},{{existingEntitlement}});">
</td>
</tr>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.addRemoveSelectedRecord = function(entitlementId,existingEntitlement){
                console.log("existingEntitlement.Selected ==== ",existingEntitlement.Selected);
}
```

It prints xistingEntitlement.Selected ==== false, even though I select the checkbox. And if I de-select checkbox then it prints true.

Note: allEntitlements is a json array. existingEntitlement is a json record. and "Selected" attribute is initialized to false.

Comment: try this ng-change="addRemoveSelectedRecord(existingEntitlement.entitlementId,existingEntitlement);" without curly braces.

Comment: Please share your js code also here.

Comment: @ Arpita Hunka Added part of JS code

Comment: Hey  maverickosama92, Thank you so much. It worked after removing curly braces mostly because then it was taking value from json